# Batch if statement multiple inputs

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

So i was writing a batch file for fun and i had a multiple choice statement, so i had it like this:

```
@echo off
title John's apples
echo.
echo John got 3 apples, he gives 1 away. How many does he have then?
echo (Please answer with ONE capital letter, or type Exit to exit.)
echo =============
echo.
echo A) 2.5
echo B) 3.459475945
echo C) 2
echo D) 1
echo Exit
echo.
:answer
set /p ans=Your Answer:
if "%
if "%ans%"=="a" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&set /p ans=Your Answer:
if "%ans%"=="b" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&set /p ans=Your Answer:
if "%ans%"=="c" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&set /p ans=Your  Answer:
if "%ans%"=="d" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&set /p ans=Your Answer:
if "%ans%"=="A" Echo Wrong! The answer was 2.
if "%ans%"=="B" Echo Wrong! The answer was 2.
if "%ans%"=="C" Echo Right! Good job! The answer was 2.
if "%ans%"=="D" Echo Wrong! The answer was 2.
if "%ans%"=="Exit" exit

Pause
Exit
```

So now i wanna know, if someone puts the wrong answer in (because you have to put a capital letter in, otherwise it will not work) it says nothing. So i wanna know how i do something like:
If A,B,C,D are not the input, print "Please enter a valid answer!"

Can anybody help? this might be asked already, sorry for that...there might be some random thingy's in the script because i was testing some around.

Comment: You could have each question in a loop. So while the answer is incorrect, ask again

Comment: @miqdadamirali Yes but i want them to show it is a non-valid answer you know its not really neccesary because most of the people aren't that dumb but i wanna improve my knowlodge about coding XD

Comment: What you could do is, when an answer is entered, validate it. If invalid, enter error message (ask again if you want to) and else continue to end/next question

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
title John's apples
echo.
echo John got 3 apples, he gives 1 away. How many does he have then?
echo (Please answer with ONE capital letter, or type Exit to exit.)
echo =============
echo.
echo A) 2.5
echo B) 3.459475945
echo C) 2
echo D) 1
echo Exit
echo.
:answer
set /p ans=Your Answer:
if "%ans%"=="a" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&goto answer
if "%ans%"=="b" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&goto answer
if "%ans%"=="c" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&goto answer
if "%ans%"=="d" Echo Please answer with a capital letter!&goto answer
if "%ans%"=="A" Echo Wrong! The answer was 2.&goto end
if "%ans%"=="B" Echo Wrong! The answer was 2.&goto end
if "%ans%"=="C" Echo Right! Good job! The answer was 2.&goto end
if "%ans%"=="D" Echo Wrong! The answer was 2.&goto end
if "%ans%"=="Exit" exit
echo Please enter a valid answer!
goto answer

:end
Pause
Exit
```

Comment: well, that worked the best for me. thanks! gotta remember this one :)

Comment: Well, if you think this answer aids you, please click on its green check-mark and later, when you have enough rep to do so, upvote it

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the seperation of capital letters is desired to single out, rather than being forgiving with the '/i' parameter. Here's my attempt.

```
@echo off
title John's apples

rem delayed expansion by preference.
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion

:init
cls
rem Added an initial label, and a clear for the 'ans' variable.
set "ans="
echo.
echo John got 3 apples, he gives 1 away. How many does he have then?
echo (Please answer with ONE capital letter, or type Exit to exit.)
echo =============
echo.
echo A) 2.5
echo B) 3.459475945
echo C) 2
echo D) 1
echo Exit
echo.
set /p ans=Your Answer:

rem Check if input is empty, then check for [a,b,c,d] in any case using the '/i' parameter,
rem Upon a valid letter, check for case. As well as a last check for a valid answer.
if not defined ans (
    echo Empty input . . . 
) else (
    if /i "!ans!" equ "exit" (
        exit /b
    ) else (
        if /i "!ans!" equ "A" (
            if "!ans!" equ "a" echo Please answer with a capital letter!
            echo Wrong! The answer was 2.
        ) else (
            if /i "!ans!" equ "B" (
                if "!ans!" equ "b" echo Please answer with a capital letter!
                echo Wrong! The answer was 2.
            ) else (
                if /i "!ans!" equ "C" (
                if "!ans!" equ "c" echo Please answer with a capital letter!
                echo Right! Good job! The answer was 2.
                ) else (
                    if /i "!ans!" equ "D" (
                        if "!ans!" equ "d" echo Please answer with a capital letter!
                        echo Wrong! The answer was 2.
                    ) else (
                        echo Invalid input . . .
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)
pause
goto :init
```

Answer (score 0):

I may have modified a little, but this works a lot better:

```
@echo off
color 0a
cls
:game
title John's apples
cls
echo John got 3 apples, he gives 1 away. How many does he have then?
echo (Please answer with ONE capital letter)
echo ===============================================================
echo A) 2.5
echo B) 3.459475945
echo C) 2
echo D) 1
echo E) Exit
set /p ans=

if %ans%== a goto capital
if %ans%== A goto wrong
if %ans%== b goto capital
if %ans%== B goto wrong
if %ans%== c goto capital
if %ans%== C goto correct
if %ans%== d goto capital
if %ans%== D goto wrong
if %ans%== e exit

:wrong
Echo Wrong! The Answer was 2.
pause
exit

:capital
echo Please answer with a capital letter!
pause 
goto game

:correct
echo Right! Good job! The answer was 2!
pause
exit
```